# Photoshop scripting - Close all except first document

Tags: photoshop-script

I'm trying to make a photoshop script that closes all documents without saving except for the first document. The first document will be a psd/psdc, the rest will be images

Currently I have the below code, this closes all documents

```
while (app.documents.length > 0) {
   app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

I've tried modifying it the same way I've done with a previous script, but it closes random documents, and not even all of them, it can leave 5-6 documents open

```
for (var i = 1; i < app.documents.length; i++) {
   app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: What do you mean by "the first document"? The order in the documents collection does not necessarily correspond with let's say the tab order of opened documents.

Comment: It’s always the first document opened and the first tab. On my other script i use app.documents[0] to refer to it and it’s always run on the correct file.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the inverted loop (so the docs are closed from the last to the first) and address them by the reference from the `documents` array, not by active document:

```js
  for (var i = documents.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    documents[i].close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES)
  }
```